# How ionic.Platform.grade works?

Tags: ionic-framework

Today I come across with `ionic.Platform.grade`. From examples, it seems like it can be use to detect a device grade.

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.grade = ionic.Platform.grade
});
```

My question is, how does it work? Based on what it label a device grade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well different parameters are used to determine this: 
1. One parameter is Operating System of device, like android OS Versions lower than Version 4 are Grade C by default.Windows Phone is determined as Grade B by default. Android versions lower than 4.4 are graded as B also. 
2. While other is availability of css features and web apis provided by default webview of that device.

For more detail see this [Documentation](https://github.com/delta98/ionic-platform-body-classes/#device-grades).
Well if you want to go into more detail, see [source of platform](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/utils/platform.js#L147) class where grade is being set. You will see at end of `_checkPlatforms`function `self.setGrade(grade);` is called by checking os version and other features of os.